# image data of bmp in C

Tags: c, binary, binaryfiles, monochrome

How to convert a monochrome bmp image file (in my case 16*16 pixels) into binary format?  This code reads the bitmap information. I have to store the pixel information into an array & it's not stored properly. I have shared the code

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

typedef struct BitMap
   {
short Signature;
long Reserved1;
long Reserved2;
long DataOffSet;
long Size;
long Width;
long Height;
short Planes;
short BitsPerPixel;
long Compression;
long SizeImage;
long XPixelsPreMeter;
long YPixelsPreMeter;
long ColorsUsed;
long ColorsImportant;
long data[16];
}BitMap;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

reading image file:

```
struct BitMap source_info;
struct Pix source_pix;

FILE *fp;
FILE *Dfp;
Dfp=fopen("filename.bin","wb")

if(!(fp=fopen("filename.bmp","rb")))
 {
    printf(" can not open file");
    exit(-1);
 }

fread(&source_info, sizeof(source_info),1,fp);
printf("%d\n",source_info.DataOffSet);
printf("%d\n",source_info.Width*source_info.Height);
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
fprintf(Dfp,"%d\t",source_info.data[i]);
```

Observed output using hex editor is
[image: hex output of monochrome bmp image]

Highlighted data i want to get stored in data array so that i can use it further in the code.

However output in filename.bin is

```
0  16777215 63 63 63 95 95 95
31 31       31 31 31 31 31 31
```

I'm new to this field. Can someone help me out where i'm going wrong?

Comment: To start with, it might be easier to compare the values if you printed hexadecimal number instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes. Actually there's no problem if the OP tries using hexadecimal numbers -- they're just the same..

Comment: output in hex is
    0x00 0xffffff 0x3f 0x3f 0x3f 0x5f 0x5f 0x5f
    0x1f 0x1f     0x1f 0x1f 0x1f 0x1f 0x1f 0x1f
Can u explain how the output is getting stored? I'm unable to get the same output

Comment: @user2967899 I've updated my answer due to your last comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's actually no problem with the data.
The problem is you're using the wrong way to print them.

Try replacing your code:

```
printf("%d\n",source_info.DataOffSet);
printf("%d\n",source_info.Width*source_info.Height);
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    fprintf(Dfp,"%d\t",source_info.data[i]);
```

with this:

```
printf("%x\n",source_info.DataOffSet);
printf("%x\n",source_info.Width*source_info.Height);
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    fprintf(Dfp,"%x\t",source_info.data[i]);
```

As `%d` is for signed decimals while `%x` is for hexadecimals. See the section of `The conversion specifier` in [the manual page of `printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

**EDITED:**

As you've posted your new questions in the comments:

> output in hex is 0x00 0xffffff 0x3f 0x3f 0x3f 0x5f 0x5f 0x5f 0x1f 0x1f 0x1f 0x1f 0x1f 0x1f 0x1f 0x1f Can u explain how the output is getting stored? I'm unable to get the same output –  user2967899 7 mins ago

here's my edited answer.

Assumptions: your working platform is just as normal, on which size of `short` is 2 bytes and of `long` it's 4.
From definition of `struct BitMap` we know the field `data` is at its offset of 0x36. Comparing of the image we know the data shall be (in hexadecimal):

```
data[0]: 0000 0000
data[1]: ffff ff00
......
```

Then the result you got seems strange since `data[1]` is `0x00ffffffff` instead of `0xffffff00`. However that's correct. This is cause by endianess, for which please read this wiki page first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness
As the hex-editor represents data in the real order of bytes, and I assume you're working with a little-endian machine (which most PC on this planet has), this order is just reversed of the real order of your data in `long`:

```
/* data in C */
unsigned long x = 305419896; /* 305419896 == 0x12345678 */

/* arithmetically the four bytes in x: */
/* 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 */

/* the real order to be observed in a hex-editor due to endianess: */
/* 0x78 0x56 0x34 0x12 */

/* so this holds true in C: */
unsigned char *a = &x;
assert(a[0] == 0x78);
assert(a[1] == 0x56);
assert(a[2] == 0x34);
assert(a[3] == 0x12);
```